# Python Selenium on how to delete input that without id and class

Tags: python, selenium, input

I'm new to python and Selenium , I'm working on a little project of create a bot automate extract data from Binance, I encounter some problem that I failed to `clear()` the date and time (html highlighted in pic below) before i `send_keys` the values that I pass into. I couldn't find any solution online , Hope that someone would help me.

[image]

Here's the python code I work on

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

#open binance margin site
website = 'https://www.binance.com/en/trade-margin/BTC_USDT'
path = '/Users/admin/Downloads/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)

#right click go to date
actions = ActionChains(driver)
right_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="kline-container css-vurnku"]')
actions.context_click(right_click).perform()

#open_date
open_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="css-17nms4o"]')
actions.click(open_date).perform()

#clear textarea field
clear_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("rc-picker-input")
actions.clear(clear_text).perform()
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solved the problem by performing `double_click` twice and `send_keys('\ue017')`to clear the textarea